# Session lost while switching from one context to another in tomcat

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a tomcat server on which I have deployed 10 web applications.
I have a Filter which reads an incoming request from one application (say "A"), reads a certain cookie value, and gets another context name (Say "B") from the database based on the value of the cookie.
This filter then rewrites the request with context A(e.g. `http://1.1.1.1/A/XYZServlet`) to a new request having context as B (e.g. `http://1.1.1.1/B/XYZServlet`).

On doing this, all the session variables are lost when the new request gets executed.
How can I make sure that the session and all the session variables(related to context A) are retained when my filter redirects the old request(context A) to the new request(context B) ?
Setting emptySessionPath = "true" in server.xml cannot be a solution due to certain architecture reasons.

Comment: delete browser cookies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat sessions are scoped to a single web application. In your case, when you switch to a different context, the session data is not lost, but simply not applicable to the new context. The scoping is controlled by the session cookie's path, it will contain the context of the creating web application and thus be only sent to the Tomcat for requests within that context.

If you want to extend the session's scope, several options come to mind: You could modify the session cookie (`JSESSIONID` by default) to the root context path `/`. Yet session cookie management is very deeply embedded in Tomcat and hard (if not impossible) to modify. I once tried to change the session cookie to be persistent with a fixed validity duration, but didn't find a way to do so.

A less elegant but maybe working way would be to duplicate the session cookie. I'm not sure if it will work, but in your filter, you could read the session cookie and create a duplicate with the target context as path. On subsequent requests, the faked session cookie would be included, possibly making your previous session data available.